# Huge performance differences between connections

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

I was trying to test the performance difference between inserting into a table directly versus inserting into a view in a different database which points to the table. I was shocked to see that a WHILE loop with 10,000 inserts into a simple table took 3 seconds but against the view it took 30 seconds.

As I investigated, I found that if I switched windows in SSMS the view performance was the same as that of the table as I thought it should have been. I then switched DBs in the view window to the table DB and inserted there and it was slow when going directly against the table.

This pointed me to the idea that there was some difference in the connections. These were different tabs in SSMS, one created from the other with -N. I didn't issue any SET commands other than SET NOCOUNT ON (in both windows) and all statistics, query plans, etc. were turned off.

When I ran SQL Profiler to look at the connections, they had identical settings. The performance difference was 100% consistent though.

I checked that there were no transactions open in either connection.

I tried opening another instance of SSMS and I cannot duplicate the slow performance (although it is happening in two out of three of my tabs in the first instance of SSMS).

This is all on a local server. I'm going to need to shut it down in about an hour and I don't know if I can reproduce this problem, so hopefully I can get some suggestions before then :)

Any other ideas on what the difference might be?

Comment: How does SQL Server account for the time discrepancy? Have you tried including actual execution plans to see if there is any difference and looking at SET STATISTICS IO and SET STATISTICS TIME results?

Comment: Just a quick comment: if it is hard / impossible to reproduce, then I wouldn't give it another thought.

Comment: Is it possible there is something in the database with the view, that is causing an extra query to take place against a different table in the same database, before it ever reachest the target insert?

Comment: @Martin - SET STATS showed no differences other than total time

Comment: @Chris - Absolutely, but I've only played around with it for an hour. I'd like to know the cause so that I can have an idea if it will be a problem when released to thousands of users on various connections :)

Comment: @Tom And have you tried the "Include Client Statistics" option in SSMS already?

Comment: @Martin - No difference other than the Client Processing Time and Total Execution Time

Comment: @Tom: Are your clients going to be hitting this through SSMS?

Comment: Regardless of how they're connecting, if it's possible to hit this problem through SSMS it's theoretically possible for it to happen through some other connection. Until I know the cause I won't know if it's realistically possible or not.

Comment: @Tom: This kind of problem is more likely a problem in SSMS than sql server itself.  Especially considering its dependent on which window/tab you are executing the sql in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you compare the rows for the slow and fast session in [`sys.dm_exec_sessions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx) and see if there's anything different.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't mention it in my message, but I checked that and dm_exec_connections

Comment: You should probably focus on trying to find where is the time difference spent. While the slow and fast query are executing, pool on sys.dm_exec_requests wait_type, wait_resource and wait_time, see if there is any obvious difference in the pattern. This should give you a hint *why* is the time difference occuring.

Comment: Btw, make sure you do not hit database and/or log growth events every Nth run which *happen* to be hit always on the same window.